# Android Listview with viewholder is returning duplicate entries

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview that has two different layout types.

1: shared
2: not shared

simple enough.

I am using a viewholder to handle recycling but for some reason i am STILL getting duplicate entries in the list view.

**BIG NOTE:** i do NOT want to change layout depending on the position of the item on the listview, therefore i dont think using getItemViewType will help, then again i may be wrong.

I am changing the item layout depending on a boolean value that is passed back from a database.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public View getItemView(final StatusItem status, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    // we'll set up the ViewHolder
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    shared = status.getShared();

    if (view == null) {
        // If view is null
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        if (shared) {
            // if the status is shared use this layout
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.status_list_view_item_shared, parent, false);
            viewHolder.OUserName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.OUserName);
            viewHolder.OUserName.setText("@" + status.getOUN());

            viewHolder.sharedText= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sharedText);
            viewHolder.sharedText.setText(status.getSharedStatus());
        } else {
            // if the status is not shared use this layout
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.status_list_view_item, parent, false);
        }

        mListViewReferences(view, status, viewHolder);
        loadProfileImages(status, viewHolder);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
```

Here is my viewHolder

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView statusUserName, timePosted, OUserName, sharedText, commentCounter, likeCounter, statusText;
    ImageButton statusLike, statusComments, statusShare, statusMenu;
    ImageView statusProfilePic;
    LinearLayout likeCounterLayout, commentCounterLayout;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this bro or Sir?

```
 @Override
public View getItemView(final StatusItem status, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View view = convertView;

// we'll set up the ViewHolder
ViewHolder viewHolder;

shared = status.getShared();

if (view == null) {
    // If view is null
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    if (shared) {
        // if the status is shared use this layout
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.status_list_view_item_shared, parent, false);
        viewHolder.OUserName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.OUserName);
        viewHolder.OUserName.setText("@" + status.getOUN());

        viewHolder.sharedText= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sharedText);
        viewHolder.sharedText.setText(status.getSharedStatus());
    } else {
        // if the status is not shared use this layout
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.status_list_view_item, parent, false);
    }        
} else {
    // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}

 mListViewReferences(view, status, viewHolder);
 loadProfileImages(status, viewHolder);
 view.setTag(viewHolder);
}
```

copy, paste and try it.. make sure they are outside your view is null if condition and its inside your getview method

Comment: lol wow, i cannot believe it was this easy. I had it like this before but with different logic an therefore i was still getting duplicate entries. Guess i got lost through the whole process and forgot to put it back outside the if/else statements. IT is what hours or programming does to you. Thank you so much.

Comment: lol..all i can do is el ol el, and say thanks to you too..and what you said "IT is what hours or programming does to you", is very true, that's why you always re-check codes....happy codding..@user123859